# print user role laravel Spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

i'm filling a table with users information now I want to get his role too, i'm using Spatie/permission library

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 @foreach (App\User::all() as $user)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ __($user->person->first_name)}}</td>
      <td>{{ __($user->person->last_name) }}</td>
      <td>{{ __($user->email) }}</td>
      <td>{{ __() }}</td>
      <td>{{ __($user->active) }}</td>
      <td><button class="edit btn btn-sm btn-warning" value="{{ __($user->id)}}">Edit</button></td>
      <td><button class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="{{ __($user->id)}}">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I don't know if I have to create the relationship on `User` model or with the Spatie installation the relationships are ready to use

Comment: Try  `$user->roles->pluck('name')` or ` `$user->getRoleNames()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use like below if you need to show all roles assigned to user with comma seperated

```
$user->roles->pluck('name')->implode(',');
```

`pluck()` will return an array so we can use `implode()` with it.

Or

```
// get the names of the user's roles
$user->getRoleNames()->pluck('name')->implode(','); // getRoleNames() returns a collection
```

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the name of the first role:

```php
$user->roles->first()->name
```

Or you can get all of the roles separated by a comma:

```php
$user->roles->implode(', ');
```